# 600 Upvotes Badge

Tags: discussion, badges

This is not really good question, but I thought there was a gold badge for 600 upvotes with 25% votes on question. I never got one even with 700/800 upvotes already and definitely nearly 50% on questions.

[Electorate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/badges/44/electorate)

Did I miss some thing? Should it be spread over a period of time. I would appreciate if it is clarified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That badge is for 600 votes **on questions**, not for 600 votes in total. So you don't qualify yet for the badge.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks.